# jQuery/Javascript leet translator plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

So i've been looking around at different places to try to get a 1337 translator that I could understand enough to work into a jQuery plugin, I feel that i'm pretty close.. but i'm not 100% what i'm doing wrong.. I'm pretty sure what I have.. isn't a jQuery plugin.. so I was hoping someone could help me figure out what i'm doing wrong.

```
(function($){
    $.fn.leet = function() {

        // Create the Phrase translations arrays
            var PhrasesEnglish = 
                new Array('crap', 'dude', 'hacker',
                          'hacks', 'you', 'cool', 'oh my god',
                          'fear', 'power', 'own',
                          'what the hell', 'elite', 'for the win', 
                          'oh really', 'good game');
            var PhrasesLeet = 
                new Array('carp', 'dood', 'haxor', 'hax', 'joo',
                          'kewl', 'omg', 'ph43', 'powwah', 'pwn', 
                          'wth', 'leet', 'ftw', 'o rly', 'gg');

            // Create the Letter translations arrays
            var LettersEnglish = 
                new Array('n', 'b', 'k', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h',
                          'p', 'm', 'r', 'l', 'o', 'q', 's', 't',
                          'u', 'x', 'w', 'y', 'z', 'c', 'a', 'j', 
                          'i', 'v', ' ');
            var LettersLeet = 
                new Array('/\\/', '|}', '|X', '[)', '3', '|=', 'gee', '|-|',
                          '|*', '(\\/)', '|2', '1', '()', '0', '$', '+',
                          '|_|', '><', '\\X/', '\'/', '2', '<', '/\\', '_|', 
                          '|', '\\/', '  ');

            // Translates text in input area to/from leet speak
            function translateText() {
                var inputString = document.getElementById('input').value;

                if (document.getElementById('conversionType').value == "e") {
                    for (i = 0; i < PhrasesEnglish.length; ++i)
                        inputString = inputString.replace(
                                new RegExp(PhrasesEnglish[i], "gi"),
                                PhrasesLeet[i]
                                );

                    for (i = 0; i < LettersEnglish.length; ++i)
                        inputString = inputString.replace(
                                new RegExp(LettersEnglish[i], "gi"),
                                LettersLeet[i]
                                );
                }
                else {
                    for (i = 0; i < LettersLeet.length; ++i)
                        inputString = inputString.replace(
                                new RegExp(RegExp.escape(LettersLeet[i]), "g"),
                                LettersEnglish[i]
                                );

                    for (i = 0; i < PhrasesLeet.length; ++i)
                        inputString = inputString.replace(
                                new RegExp(RegExp.escape(PhrasesLeet[i]), "g"),
                                PhrasesEnglish[i]
                                );
                }

                document.getElementById('input').value = inputString;
            }

        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

This is what i've got as far as the plugin, mind you I found this online and am trying to rework it.. so the html is kinda horrid atm..

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="leet.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("div").leet();
        });
    </script>

    <body>

        <div style="border: solid 1px Black; 
                    padding: 5px; width: 350px; 
                    background-color: White;">
            <label for="input">
                Enter message here:</label><br />
            <textarea id="input" name="input" rows="10" cols="40" 
            style="font-weight: bold;
                   background-image: url('leetBG.png'); 
                   background-attachment: fixed; 
                   background-position: 160px 165px;
                   background-repeat: no-repeat;"></textarea>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Translate" 
             onclick="translateText();" />
            <select id="conversionType">
                <option value="e">English -> 1337</option>
                <option value="3">1337 -> English</option>
            </select>
        </div>

    </body>
```

Comment: You really should use one object and not two arrays for the words.

Comment: Ok, i'm sure that's probably the way to go.. Like I said.. I found this online and i'm trying to rework it for a jQuery plugin.. but i'm not that great at it yet.. so really anything helps

Comment: Also not 100% on this but it may be better practice(?) to create the arrays literally rather than as an object so var PhrasesEnglish = ['blah','blah','blah' etc...];

Comment: I think that you want to have the translate text function outside of your .leet() extension. I'm pretty sure it wont be able to find that function in your onclick handler. In fact, I don't really see what the point of having this as a jquery extension does.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the translate text function from it's own function to just a part of the extension. Then call the extension onclick so

```
(function($){
$.fn.leet = function() {

    // Create the Phrase translations arrays

        var PhrasesEnglish = ['crap', 'dude', 'hacker',
                      'hacks', 'you', 'cool', 'oh my god',
                      'fear', 'power', 'own',
                      'what the hell', 'elite', 'for the win', 
                      'oh really', 'good game'];
        var PhrasesLeet = ['carp', 'dood', 'haxor', 'hax', 'joo',
                      'kewl', 'omg', 'ph43', 'powwah', 'pwn', 
                      'wth', 'leet', 'ftw', 'o rly', 'gg'];

    // Create the Letter translations arrays

        var LettersEnglish = ['n', 'b', 'k', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h',
                      'p', 'm', 'r', 'l', 'o', 'q', 's', 't',
                      'u', 'x', 'w', 'y', 'z', 'c', 'a', 'j', 
                      'i', 'v', ' '];
        var LettersLeet = ['/\\/', '|}', '|X', '[)', '3', '|=', 'gee', '|-|',
                      '|*', '(\\/)', '|2', '1', '()', '0', '$', '+',
                      '|_|', '><', '\\X/', '\'/', '2', '<', '/\\', '_|', 
                      '|', '\\/', '  '];
    // Translates text in input area to/from leet speak

        var id = $(this).attr('id');            
        var inputString = document.getElementById(id).value;

        if (document.getElementById('conversionType').value == "e") {
            for (i = 0; i < PhrasesEnglish.length; ++i)
                inputString = inputString.replace(
                        new RegExp(PhrasesEnglish[i], "gi"),
                        PhrasesLeet[i]
                        );

                for (i = 0; i < LettersEnglish.length; ++i)
                    inputString = inputString.replace(
                            new RegExp(LettersEnglish[i], "gi"),
                            LettersLeet[i]
                            );
        }
        else {
            for (i = 0; i < LettersLeet.length; ++i)
                inputString = inputString.replace(
                        new RegExp(RegExp.escape(LettersLeet[i]), "g"),
                        LettersEnglish[i]
                        );

            for (i = 0; i < PhrasesLeet.length; ++i)
                inputString = inputString.replace(
                        new RegExp(RegExp.escape(PhrasesLeet[i]), "g"),
                        PhrasesEnglish[i]
                        );
        }

        document.getElementById(id).value = inputString;

    };
})(jQuery);​
```

Your onclick handler will look something like this

```
<input type="submit" value="Translate" onclick="$('#input').leet();" />
```

Here's the fiddle (I don't know how people can read that, I thought it wasn't working properly until I deciphered it.) http://jsfiddle.net/ThD29/1/

Also, the translation from 1337 -> English isn't working. Apparently RegExp has no method called 'escape'. I don't know much about regular expressions so hopefully someone else can point to the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot James, that's a TON of help.. and I actually understand what's going on. I think I can ask around to see if I can get the back to english part working.. or someone may even figure that out as well